# Wechat Moments not in the options of Intent.createChooser matching ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, share, wechat

I am now planning to share some text and link to SNS app in the phone.
  And the code I use is below:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "the word i like to say");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share with below apps"));
    return shareIntent;
```

there are so many options but unfortunately there is no Wechat Moments in it. Of course I can use shareSDK to achieve that, but the latter one has no Facebook/LinkedIn/Google+ in it. And there are too many 3rd libs included which I don't like. What is more, to show share options in two seperate menus is quite wired.

So, is there a way that I can add the option "Wechat moments" into the previous implementation(just like the image below) ? That will be quite helpful.

[image: send to moments added into the options]

Comment: who down-voted the question can given any reason for that?

Comment: I just find the workaround for that. It is simple that I missed the shareSDK has exntention which support google+/linkedIn...So I dont need to use native share support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wechat only accepts image.
Below will works.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(File obj));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share with below apps"));
return shareIntent;
```

Comment: It is a little late for me, but really is the reason why I found no moments there. Thanks!